Presenting "Condition" batch creation setup for users in a ship buoyancy simulation software
This is a re-write of this question, as I was advised that I over-simplified the problem there.
I am writing a simulation software that takes a 3D model of a ship (or any other floating vessel), and simulates how it behaves in the water. User can define a Condition - a snapshot position of the ship at certain immersion (draft), heel and trim angles, velocity, etc., and the software simulates that Condition and outputs all sorts of data. A lot of parameter may be input or output, depending on the use case - for example, user does not know the draft, but knows the weight of the ship, so they input the weight, and software finds the draft. Or, the user knows the draft, and then software estimates the weight. These parameters are of different types - numeric, multi choice (checkbox), single choice (radiobuttons / dropdown lists), etc. User can define immersion, angles, weight, center of gravity, velocity, resistance, power, create various forces acting on the ship with their vectors and magnitudes, etc. There are typically around 50 parameters that user has to define per single Condition.
Software then has to determine if user defined the Condition enough to solve it (meaning it is not under or over defined), and then solve it.
This is where it gets complicated: user may want to define a pattern of Conditions, sort of a batch mode, for example, vary heel angle from 0° to 180° every 1° in order to get a stability curve. That's 180 Conditions. They may also want to run this at 3 different weights, say 100 t., 110 t. and 120 t., so that's 3 x 180 = 540 Conditions. Or, alternatively, they may want to set up a matrix-like table to set up specific combinations of variables, for example:
Heel 10° 20° 25°
Trim 1°  2°  2.2°

(This would be 3 different Conditions).
Or, they may want to set a Goal and make the software adjust some values to converge on a particular target value. For example, adjust Velocity and Trim angle to find minimum Resistance.
My question is, how should I present this in the UI to make it simple, comprehensible, non-confusing yet flexible for the users? I've tried many different approaches, but they are all limiting in one way or another. One of the most important points is that if user needs a batch of Conditions, their common values (those that are no changing) should be linked together, so that the user doesn't have to go through all the hundreds of other Conditions to change that value. Yet they should be able to "break out" any value from the link, for example Draft value should be linked through all the Conditions, yet made unique and different value for one particular Condition.
What I tried:

I've tried "master Condition" approach (user defines everything in one Condition, where every numeric field may contain one or more values, for ex. 5° or 5°, 6°, 8° or 1° : 180° : 1°), and then afterwards ask them if they want a matrix-like table or if they want to "multiply" all possible combinations of multi-value parameters. And then:
A) Create all Conditions as children of that "master" Condition, linking their parameter values to it, except the varied parameters;
B) Same, but not linking values, and having something like "copy value to all other Conditions" button next to every parameter;
C) Only show that "master" Condition, and imply the existence of others through something like "Condition 1: 180 variations";
I tried allowing only single value inputs for every parameter, and then have separate "vary parameters" feature that allows setting up multiplication/matrix table;
Tried multi-level, tree-like structure of Conditions with parent/child relations to handle parameter inheritance
Etc.

And also having an option for the user not to enter some values at all, but have them automatically adjusted based on a Goal makes it even more confusing for the user.
I've been at this for several months now, and can't find an elegant solution for creating and presenting such a flexible system without making it complicated and daunting with a steep learning curve. This is a complex issue, and even describing it bloated this post, but I didn't want to leave out any details.
Can anyone suggest how to solve this in an elegant and user-friendly way? If you were the user, what would be the ideal solution for you here? Any guidance would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

It is surely an improvement that you now gave us a lot more real context from your problem, still I have my doubts outsiders like us can answer this - but you can wait a day or two how it does. Oh, and some braindead hardliner here vote to close this as a "3rd party resource request" question, I would remove the part "Does anyone know of any other softwares" from the question, just ask for an approach, such phrases sometimes trigger close votes

@DocBrown Much appreciated! I fixed my question as per your recommendation. I will patiently wait for any suggestions.

@DocBrown, perhaps this is not the right place to ask for such questions? I am struggling to find a community where such broad design inquiries would be appropriate and have the highest chance of receiving an answer. I understand the "outsider" problem, and that it is asking a lot for people to read through all this and come up with something, since this is not an easy question to answer. I would even be open to paying someone to offer a good theoretical solution to this, but again, I'm not sure where should I go with such inquiry.

From /help/dont-ask - "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much" - books have been written on breaking down problems and UX design so I think a close vote should be considered. Maybe an entire book is too much here, but I think the scope of the question is too larger for this site.

I think that you arr trying to make a too tight coupling between the user interface and the simulation engine.
What about splitting the user interface into several, largely independent modules. For example

Generating a set of Conditions. This can take several forms, but would always result in a set of Conditions.
Simulating multiple Conditions.
Performing an optimisation based on a Goal.

For the generating part, I would probably give the user the option to fill a table, or to let them write a script in a Domain Specific Language (DSL).

Thank you, this is good advice. Thing is, if I decouple how Conditions are defined in the UI and in the simulation engine, then I need to translate these definitions when user creates Conditions or when they want to modify them. I thought that binding UI elements to the Conditions directly would result in less code to maintain.
As for your advice, once these Conditions are generated, question is, how does user modify them in batch to change common variables, or change the pattern of the set? Table would be way too big because of the number of variables that go into each Condition.

If I understood the answer correctly, that's where the DSL comes into play. The DSL is the input to the Condition generator, and the user or UI manipulates the expressions in the DSL, not the generated Conditions. You may find that at the end of the day, letting the user write statements in the DSL may be less restrictive and more powerful while requiring less UI coding, but YMMV.

How about allowing the user to enter formulae for variables?
So for example at the top of the spec you could define the number of runs n
n : [1..180]

then the Heel angle in your example could be defined as
Heel : n 

If you want the matrix for Trim
Trim : n/10

If you want the combination of Heel and Trim
n : [1..(180*180)]
Heel : n % 180
Trim : (n % 180) /10

Obviously this can get complex quick, so you can provide some helper functions for common scenarios and expand as required.
